# how to get sum of distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have an SQL query that return a distinct records

```
select distinct 
VENDOR_NUMBER,VENDOR_NAME,CHECK_DATE,
EMAIL_ADDRESS,FAX,check_amount 
from MOF_AP_REMITTANCE_GFOS_HEADER_HISTORY 
where VENDOR_NUMBER = 4382501 and DATEPART(yy, CHECK_DATE) = '2015'



4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 1460.000

4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-29 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 5556.000

4382501 | Zayani | 2015-02-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | **730.000**

4382501 | Zayani | 2015-02-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | **11781.000**
```

i need to get the sum of each record if i have more than one record
i need the result to look like the following

```
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 1460.000

4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-29 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 5556.000

4382501 | Zayani | 2015-02-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | **12511.000**
```

i tried to use SUM function but i am getting wrong result since the data in DB look like this

```
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 1460.000
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 1460.000
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-01-29 | xx@bb.com | NULL | 5556.000
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-02-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | **730.000**
4382501 | Zayani | 2015-02-15 | xx@bb.com | NULL | **11781.000**
```

if you can see the second record is duplicated thats why i used distinct

any suggestion?

Comment: Why have you chosen to aggregate those two records, but not the others (and in particular the first, which appears to be equivalent on all other fields)?

Comment: GROUP BY and use SUM(check_amount). Are you really using both MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
select VENDOR_NUMBER,VENDOR_NAME,CHECK_DATE,
       EMAIL_ADDRESS,FAX,SUM(check_amount ) as check_amount 
from (select distinct 
             VENDOR_NUMBER,VENDOR_NAME,CHECK_DATE,
             EMAIL_ADDRESS,FAX,check_amount 
      from MOF_AP_REMITTANCE_GFOS_HEADER_HISTORY 
      where VENDOR_NUMBER = 4382501 and DATEPART(yy, CHECK_DATE) = '2015'))
GROUP BY VENDOR_NUMBER,VENDOR_NAME,CHECK_DATE,EMAIL_ADDRESS,FAX
```

Comment: You can remove DISTINCT now since it has no purpose anymore.

Comment: i did this before but i am getting wrong result, cuz it will select other records not distinct

Comment: @Noora add the distinct query in to a subquery if you need to use it, then group and sum the result from that, see updated answer.